# Hexdump reverse command

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, hexdump

The [hexdump](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hexdump.1.html) command converts any file to hex values.

But what if I have hex values and I want to reverse the process, is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a similar tool called `xxd`. If you run `xxd` with just a file name it dumps the data in a fairly standard hex dump format:

```
# xxd bdata
0000000: 0001 0203 0405
......
```

Now if you pipe the output back to `xxd` with the `-r` option and redirect that to a new file, you can convert the hex dump back to binary:

```
# xxd bdata | xxd -r >bdata2
# cmp bdata bdata2
# xxd bdata2
0000000: 0001 0203 0405
```

Comment: Conveniently, `xxd -r` also accepts `hexdump` output as input.

Comment: What do I do if I have a file which isn't formatted with things like colons, spaces, and newlines, and is just a stream matching `[0-9A-F]*` until the end of the file?

Answer (score 6):

I've written a short AWK script which reverses `hexdump -C` output back to the
original data.  Use like this:

```
reverse-hexdump.sh hex.txt > data
```

Handles '*' repeat markers and generating original data even if binary.
`hexdump -C` and `reverse-hexdump.sh` make a data round-trip pair.  It is
available here:

- [GitHub reverse-hexdump repo](https://github.com/mfleetwo/reverse-hexdump)
- Direct to [reverse-hexdump.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mfleetwo/reverse-hexdump/master/reverse-hexdump.sh)

Comment: @Zibri
Yes my script does handle `*` repeat markers `hexdump -C` produces without the `-v` option.  The example in the README shows it working.  There are 5 unit test cases confirming this.

If you really have a case where this doesn't work please raise an issue in the github repo.

Comment: My bad.. good work.. I noticed 5 minute after and I forgot to remove the comment.

Answer (score 5):

### Restore `file`, given only the output of `hexdump file`

If you only have the output of `hexdump file` and want to restore the original file, first note that [hexdump's default output depends on the endianness of the system you ran hexdump on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/55772/187122)!

If you have access to the system that created the dump, you can determinate its endianness using below command:

```
[[ "$(printf '\01\03' | hexdump)" == *0103* ]] && echo big || echo little
```

#### Reversing little-endian hexdump

This is the most common case. All x86/x64 systems are little-endian. If you don't know the endianness of the system that ran `hexdump file`, try this.

```
sed 's/ \(..\)\(..\)/ \2\1/g;$d' dump | xxd -r
```

The `sed` part converts `hexdump`'s format into `xxd`'s format, at least so far that `xxd -r` works.

#### Reversing big-endian hexdump

```
sed '$d' dump | xxd -r
```

#### Known Bugs (see comment section)

- A trailing null byte is added if the original file was of odd length (e.g. 1, 3, 5, 7, ...,  byte long).
- Repeating sections of the original file are not restored correctly if they were `hexdump`ed using a `*`.

You can check your dump for above problematic cases by running below command:

```
grep -qE '^\*|^[0-9a-f]*[13579bdf] *$' dump && echo bug || echo ok
```

### Better alternative to create hexdumps in the first place

Besides the non-posix (and therefore not so portable) `xxd` there is `od` (**o**ctal **d**ump) which should be available on all unix-like systems as it is specified by posix:

```
od -tx1 -An -v
```

Will print a he**x**adecimal dump, grouping digits as single bytes (`-tx1`), with **n**o **A**ddress prefixes (`-An`, similar to `xxd -p`) and without abbreviating repeated sections as `*` (`-v`). You can reverse such a dump using `xxd -r -p`.

Comment: This wasn't necessary for me (MacOS Mojave)

Comment: Does not work if the last line ends with 0A, because it's replaced by 0A00.

Comment: @Smeterlink Thank you for this observation! You are right: This command produces a trailing null byte which wasn't in the original file if the length in bytes was an odd number. I also found another bug. `hexdump` may hide repeated parts using a `*`. This command also cannot restore these parts correctly. Example: `yes | head -n100 | hexdump | sed -E 's/ /: /;s/ (..)(..)/ \2\1/g' | xxd -r` prints only 8 `y` instead of 100. Fixing these things would require more than this one-liner. Maybe I add another script in the future.

Comment: You can avoid the `*` bug if you run `hexdump` with the `-v` option.

Comment: Or you can specify the hexdump format so you can just use `xxd -p -r mydump`: `hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' mybinaryfile > mydump`

Comment: @dagelf For me, the whole point of the question was to reverse a hexdump for which you do not have the binary file. In that case, dumping in another format is not possible. Either way, I'll have to update this answer, as some people claimed `xdd -r` to work on the default output of `hexdump` all by itself.

Comment: Keep in mind that people with the obvious use case will stumble upon this question and its answers too: those who have the binary file, but no other way to transfer it than telnet or serial access to a console where it is located - so no need to update it. Also, Google already has it indexed for searches about reversing hexdump :-0

Answer (score 3):

**As someone who sucks at bash**, I could not understand the examples already posted.
Here is what would have helped me when I was originally searching:

Take your text file "AYE.TXT" and convert it into a hex dump called "BEE.TXT"

```
xxd -p "AYE.TXT" > "BEE.TXT"
```

Take your hex dump file ("BEE.TXT") and covert it back to ascii file "CEE.TXT"

```
xxd -r -p "BEE.TXT" > "CEE.TXT"
```

Now that you have some simple working code, feel free to check out
"xxd -help" on the command line for an explanation of what all those flags do.
(That part is the easy part, the hard part is the specifics of the bash syntax)

Comment: From man xxd: Use the combination -r -p to read plain hexadecimal dumps without line number information and without a particular column layout.

Thank you @KANJICODER that was the quick working answer!

Answer (score 1):

### If you don't have `xxd`, use `hexdump`, `od`, `perl` or `python`:

The following all give the same output:

```
# If you only have hexdump
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' mybinaryfile > mydump

# This gives exactly the same output as:
xxd -p mybinaryfile > mydump

# Or, much slower:
od -v -t x1 -An < mybinaryfile | tr -d "\n " > mydump 

# Or, the fastest:
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=\1e6} $_=unpack "H*"' < mybinaryfile > mydump

# Or, if you somehow have Python, and not Perl:
python -c "print(open('mybinaryfile','rb').read().hex())" > mydump
```

Then you can copy and paste, or pipe the output, and convert back with:

```
xxd -r -p mydump mybinaryfileagain

# Or
xxd -r -p < mydump > mybinaryfileagain
```

The `hexdump` command is available almost everywhere, and is usually part of the default `busybox` - if it's not linked, you can try running `busybox hexdump` or `busybox xxd`.

If `xxd` is not available to reverse the data, then you can try awk

### The old days: Zmodem

In the old days we used to use X/Y/Zmodem which is available in the package `lrzsz` which can tolerate lossy comms - but it's a bidirectional protocol so the binaries need to be running at the same time and there needs to be bidirectional comms:

```
# Demo on local machine, using FIFOs
mkfifo /tmp/fifo-in
mkfifo /tmp/fifo-out
sz -b mybinaryfile > /tmp/fifo-out < /tmp/fifo-in
mkdir out; cd out
rz -b < /tmp/fifo-out > /tmp/fifo-in
```

Luckily, screen supports receiving Zmodem, so if you're in a screen session:

```
screen
telnet somehost
```

Then type `Ctrl+A` and `:` and then `zmodem catch` and `Enter`. Then inside the screen on the remote host, issue:

```
# sz -b mybinaryfile
```

Press `Enter` when you see the string starting with "!!!".

When you see "Transfer Complete", you may want to run `reset` if you want to continue the terminal session normally.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tonne of more elegant ways to get this done, but I've quickly hacked something together that Works for Me (tm) when regenerating a binary file from a hex dump generated by `hexdump -C some_file.bin`:

```
sed 's/\(.\{8\}\)  \(..\) \(..\) \(..\) \(..\) \(..\) \(..\) \(..\) \(..\)/\1: \2\3 \4\5 \6\7 \8\9/g' some_file.hexdump | sed 's/\(.*\)  \(..\) \(..\) \(..\) \(..\) \(..\) \(..\) \(..\) \(..\)  |/\1 \2\3 \4\5 \6\7 \8\9  /g' | sed 's/.$//g' | xxd -r > some_file.restored
```

Basically, uses 2 `sed` processeses, each handling it's part of each line. Ugly, but someone might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

This program reverses `hexdump -C` output back to the original data.

```bash
Usage:

make
make test
./unhexdump -i inputfile -o outputfile
```

see https://github.com/zhouzq-thu/unhexdump!

Answer (score 0):

i found more simple solution:

bin2hex

`echo -n "abc" | hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x"'`

hex2bin

`echo -n "616263" | grep -Eo ".{2}" | sed 's/\(.*\)/\\x\1/' | tr -d '\n' | xargs -0 echo -ne`