# Converting a hexdump back to a rar

Tags: reverse-engineering, computer-forensics

I have a plaintext file that I wish to convert to something I can extract.

```
00000000  52 61 72 21 1a 07 01 00  f3 e1 82 eb 0b 01 05 07  |Rar!............|

00000010  00 06 01 01 80 80 80 00  3b fd 42 9f 51 02 03 31  |........;.B.Q..1|

00000020  a0 02 06 82 03 80 83 02  20 15 d4 6e 5b 46 b6 57  |........ ..n[F.W|

00000030  80 03 01 09 69 6e 73 74  72 2e 74 78 74 30 01 00  |....instr.txt0..|

00000040  03 0f 44 a5 ce af b3 09  b9 96 44 22 f4 99 ef 04  |..D.......D"....|
```

This is part of the file which made me believe it is a rar file. I tried using xxd with the -r option to no avail.

I tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724144/hexdump-command-reverse) but it also didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

To solve my own question, and for future reference.

Use vim's visual block select to copy just the hex values into 'justhexvalues.txt'.

Then use xxd:

> `xxd -r -p justhexvalues.txt answer.rar`

That was it.